# How to display a List within a tooltip?

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

**I like to show a List in a tooltip, but i don't really knwo how to perform this.**

Background: Users are able to vote some categories. I display a Chart (Telerik) that shows the amount of votes for a specific category. Now i want to display a tooltip with a list of users when the mouse cursor hovers over the respective series items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retemplate the tooltip style :
ex:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" >
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" >
               <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a string with the concatenation of the elements in your list and put that string as the tool tip.